# How to pass a value to a method like UIColor does

Tags: swift

I want to call a method like this:

`myMethod(myType: .value1)
//or
myMethod(myType: .value2)`

Where `.value1` and `.value2` are static string values like `"moobs"` and `"notMoobs"`.

Similar to how UIColor does it:

`blah.color = .clear
//or
setColor(.clear)`

Not sure what to search for or what it might be called.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
enum ValueTypes: String {
    case value1 = "moobs"
    case value2 = "notMoobs"
}

func myMethod(myType: ValueTypes) {
    //Your code goes here
}

myMethod(myType: .value1)
myMethod(myType: .value2)
```

Comment: Ah yes enums... forgot about them.  Thank you @J. Koush

Answer (score 2):

Add extension to String and add static variables,

```
extension String {
    static let value1 = "moobs"
    static let value2 = "notMoobs"
}
```

And use that with your method,

```
myMethod(myType: .value1)
```

Comment: Interesting.  Not sure my data belongs on the `String` class but good idea non the less.